# jQuery On event Off unbind automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind, jquery-on

Is there a way to automatically unbind all "on" events that were set on an element? I have found a solution but i don't know if it is the corect one.

```
$(document).off('click', 'li').on('click', 'li', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // some stuff goes here
});
```

EDIT:

I have tried all the suggested answers but none worked as i wanted. Maybe it was my mistake that i didn't give enough information: the point is that all my content is loaded dynamically like in tabs and some tabs could be loaded more time.

I have tried this $('li').off().on('click', function(){
});
-> did not work

Also have tried this $('li').unbind().on('click', function(){
});
-> did not work.

Comment: check out .unbind() http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: Your solution is the correct one, don't use unbind() as suggested in the answers as `off()` is the preferred method in the jQuery API as of version 1.7

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `unbind()` or `off()` to remove all event handlers from an object.

```
$('#myNode').unbind();
```

`off()` is preferred way to do this in jQuery 1.7+ (noted by @[Krishna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/489512/krishna)).

```
$('#myNode').off();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajmtX/1/)

Comment: Note that _As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements._

Comment: @Krishna That is why I asked the question in my previous comment, because I have added the event like this $(document).on('click', 'li', function(e){});

Comment: Yes. As @Krishna said, the preferred way to do this is with `off()`, in jQuery 1.7+, but it will work both ways. I updated my answer to demonstrate both methods. See the JSFiddle for confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) without parameters to do this:

```
$('li').unbind();
```

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/):

> In the simplest case, with no arguments, `.unbind()` removes all handlers attached to the elements.

As of jQuery 1.7, [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) are the preferred methods to bind and unbind event handlers.

So to remove all handlers from an element, use this:

```
$('li').off();
```

or for specific handlers:

```
$('p').off('click hover');
```

And to add or bind event handlers, you can use

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').off();//Remove all event handlers from all li elements:
$('li').off('click');//Remove specific event - click
```

From documentation [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/),

*The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on().*

From [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) documentation,

*As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements.*

```
$('li').unbind(); //removes all event handlers
$('li').unbind('click');//removes specific event - click
```